# Long i (ī) in XeLaTeX if one cannot use xunicode

Tags: unicode

I am working on an article for which I need to use the package `amsmath` and several newcommands defining logic variables, e.g., `\newcommand{\nec}{\mathsf{nec}}`. Since the topic of the article is Sanskrit logic, I would also need to be able to type diacritics. I tried with the `xunicode` package, but this clashes with the newcommands mentioned above. I thus tried to input diacritics one by one, e.g., `\={a}` for long a (ā) and so on. This works pretty well in most cases, but in the case of the long i I get the wrong result, namely a normal i with an added line over it instead of ī. Does anyone know of the solution? I typeset with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\=i` is supposed to give a macron over a dotted i. To get a macron over an i without the dot, write `\=\i`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\=i \=\i
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the dotted version `\=i` is not needed, then this can be redefined to provide the dotless version. This depends on the font encoding. The example shows it for font encoding `T1`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{T1}{i}{\=\i}

\begin{document}
Ibn-S\=in\=a
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution: Using the package {unicode-math} instead of {xunicode}.

Comment: Probably you simply loaded xunicode to early, nowadays you don't need to load it yourself. Packages like fontspec and unicode-math will do it for you.